# Collapsing vertical menu in element.io

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I try to create a layout with [element.io](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu) which has a collapsing sidebar menu.

It works quite well, the only problem is that I do not gain anything since the width of the menu and the content part are fixed.

My code looks like this:

```
<template>
    <el-row>
        <el-col :span="4">
            <template>
                <el-menu :router="true"
                         :default-active="$route.path"
                         background-color="#545c64"
                         text-color="#fff"
                         active-text-color="#ffd04b"
                         :collapse="isCollapse"
                         class="el-menu-vertical-demo"
                >
                    <template v-for="rule in routes">
                        <el-menu-item :index="rule.path">
                            <i :class="rule.icon"></i>
                            <span slot="title">{{ rule.name }}</span>

                        </el-menu-item>
                    </template>
                </el-menu>
            </template>

        </el-col>

        <el-col :span="20">
            <el-row>
                <el-radio-group v-model="isCollapse" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <el-radio-button :label="true" :disabled="isCollapse" border>
                        <i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>
                    </el-radio-button>
                    <el-radio-button :label="false" :disabled="!isCollapse" border>
                        <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
                    </el-radio-button>
                </el-radio-group>
            </el-row>

            <el-row>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </el-row>
        </el-col>
    </el-row>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                routes: this.$router.options.routes,
                activeLink: null,
                isCollapse: false
            };
        },
        mounted: function () {
        },
        methods: {
        }
    };
</script>
```

How can I fix it so the content block will occupy 100% of the available width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a simple solution.

First, I moved to element-io elements. The menu is now embedded inside `el-aside` tag, while the main part is embedded inside an `el-container` tag.

Second, I added a dynamic css class to the `el-aside` tag:

```
<el-aside v-bind:class="[isCollapse ? 'menu-collapsed' : 'menu-expanded']">
```

Now, if you don't want to mess around with transitions, simply add to the `el-menu` component `:collapse-transition="false"` and that's it!